# How to instantiate a sprite from a sprite sheet using script in unity?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

We are creating a 2D top down rpg, and we have multiple textures, and we need to be able to change which sprite sheet its reading from in order to change the look of the walls and floor in each room. It has the same basic tiles just they need to look different. Like the corner of a cabin, to the corner of an office building.

At the moment we are taking the sprite sheet, splitting it up, and making prefabs out of it for placement by script in the game. Is there a way to do this automatically because we have a lot of textures, and its too many to make into prefabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the sprites are in your Assets/Resources directory, you can load them programmatically as follows:

```
Sprite[] spriteSheetSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("spriteSheetName);
```

This will yield a `Sprite` array containing all of the sprites from your spritesheet, indexed by their order on the sheet.

A requirement to use this is that the image's import settings must be set to `Sprite (2D and UI)` and `Multiple`. The other settings should not matter. Also, the sprites must be somewhere inside of your `Assets/Resources` directory, though they can be in a subfolder. To access/load sprites in a subfolder, just append the name of the folder to the beginning of the string, as follows (this assumes that your tiles are in the `Assets/Resources/Tiles` directory:

```
Sprite[] roadSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Tiles/roadSpriteSheet");
```

Note that loading resources like this is quite heavy on hardware usage, so do not do this many times in your game. A way around this is to have a static `SpriteManager` class, or similar, that keeps references to sprites inside of itself, which classes can request, so that each sprite is loaded a maximum of once.

```
static class SpriteManager 
{
    private Sprite[] _officeSprites;
    static SpriteManager {}
    public Sprite[] OfficeSprites 
    {
        if(_officeSprites == null)
            _officeSprites = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Tiles/officeSpriteSheet");
        return _officeSprites;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set sprites default import settings to multiple rather than single?

Comment: @ThatsATen As far as I know, there is unfortunately not by default. However, you should be able to write a short editor script to achieve the same goal. An example can be found here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/can-i-change-the-default-import-settings.50043/, though that one regards models.

Comment: Well we are trying to make a game where a texture can be added by the user the same way a retexture works. Only its rooms specific, allowing the user to add their own rooms to the game. Would the editor script still work after the game is built and distributed?

Comment: @ThatsATen it would not, since the editor script only works... in the editor. However, you could probably implement something to load sprites manually from file. I've never done this before, but maybe you want to ask another question either here or on Unity Answers.

Answer (score 0):

pick your instantiated prefab, say

```
GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(yourPrefab) as GameObject;
```

and get for example a sprite

```
Sprite yourSprite = Resources.Load("sprite" typeOf(Sprite));
```

and change the prite

```
go.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = yourSprite;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I create **ScriptableObject** to store the sprite, and load the created asset at runtime, it quite convenient than prefab.

```
AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("pathToPngfile")
```

This will load all the sprite at the specific path